# Reflect the QPixmap

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have an object QPixmap, how to get his reflection without QImage?
Now I do it using QImage (PyQt4):

```
tmp_image = QImage("./templates/{type}/{name}.png".format(type=tpl_type, name=tpl_name))
pixmap_reflect = QPixmap().fromImage(tmp_image.mirrored(horizontal=True, vertical=False))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use QPixmap's `transformed()` ([see this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#transformed)), using a scale as the transform (a scale of (1,-1) should do the trick I think). I'm assuming all functionality is available in PyQt. Don't use that myself.

Comment: Thanks, that working `pixmap_reflect = pixmap.transformed(QTransform().scale(-1, 1))`